# Install CoreCtrl (GPU GUI) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: amd-graphics, gpu, amdgpu, fancontrol

I read about "CoreCtrl" (GPU GUI) which looks promising but I cannot find it in the repository.
Do you have any ideas how I can install it?

Thanks.

[More about CoreCtrl](https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The website has the instructions right on the page, close to the end of page:

> ### Ubuntu
>
> Add the [`Ernst ppa-mesarc`](https://launchpad.net/%7Eernstp/+archive/ubuntu/mesarc) PPA.
>
> Then run:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install corectrl
> ```

Focal is supported, so this is literally everything you need.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see the PPA. Now it's working. :-)

Comment: In other words, just type this in terminal: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ernstp/mesarc`

Comment: Then: sudo apt-get update
then: sudo apt install corectrl